# Can I write if(isset($_POST['submit'])) twice in a same page

Tags: php, html

I have one form with one submit button. But in script I need to check `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` twice in a same page.

for example.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //some code
}

//html code

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //some code
}
```

Does it work? Is there any problem to do this.

Comment: So, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Try, write the code and what ever you need to test it and ***try***

Comment: Why not try executing it?

Comment: it will work and no theres not problem with that...

Comment: u can, but y need like that, `if(button press) {// run all work}`

Comment: @Fred-ii- not at all, why do you think that ?

Comment: Sorry..I am fresher with no experience at all...

Comment: question's too unclear. what is it exactly that you want to achieve here?

Comment: @Sudip977 That's why you need to try, don't be scared to try, nothing is gonna explode, the world isn't gonna go under if there's a syntax error or your code doesn't work, the important thing is that you ***try***

Comment: @Fred-ii- first one is executed as first so how could last one get precedence ?

Comment: @MarekJanoud pop an answer then; I'm passing on this one.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - No. I dont know about stack overflow. I am new here. I dont know about points.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but no need tho.
You can use variable to define that $_REQUEST and use that variable
**for example:**

```
<?php
    $submitted = (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;
    if($submited)
    {
      //some code
    }
 ?>
    //html code
 <?php
    if($submitted)
    {
      //some code
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: `$submited = (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;
    if($submited)
    {
      //some code
    }` - Huh? You're using ternary AND an `if`??

Comment: I am using ternary to set variable true or false. than if he need to execute some check he can use variable than calling all again.

Comment: What :D.
Ternary one line operation , how can do he's question answer with 1 line ternary with html code inside.

Comment: what do you mean "what ternary"? *lol* - what do you this is `(isset($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;`

Comment: it could be writen as `$submited = isset($_POST['submit']);` but thats all, code in answer prevent for example `$_POST['submit'] = true;` later and before second check

Comment: Go read php.net ternary operator :D . $submitted = (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false; this is to set variable than refer to it without doing if(isset($_POST['submit'])){}; every time when u need to check that.

Comment: Marek Nice one THumbs Up

Answer (score 0):

Ya, It's possible to use twice if(isset($_POST['submit'])) based on your requirements.

It will be best to have a named submit button element within the form as below.

```
<form name="form" action="<?php echo __FILE__ ?>" method="POST">
  <input name="Form1" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['Form1'])){ 
    var_dump($_POST);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` does not change the value of its input variable.

since $_POST is a variable and it can be used anywhere along the post
you can check its value using `isset()` as many times as you need without any problem

good luck

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit1']) ) {
    ...
}

if ( isset($_POST['submit2']) ) {
    ...
}
```

Name every submit form differently and use name in **if ( isset($_POST['name']) )**